# How to use shiny app as a target in drake

Tags: r, shiny, drake-r-package

How to pass previous target (`df`) to `ui` and `server` functions that I use in the next command `shinyApp`. My plan looks like this:

```
plan <- drake_plan(
  df = faithful,
  app = shinyApp(ui, server)
)
```

`ui` and `server` are copied from the [shiny tutorial](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/basics.html). There's only one difference -  I changed `faithful` to `df` (data in the previous target). 
Now I'm getting an error:

```
Warning: Error in $: object of type 'closure' is not subsettable
  [No stack trace available]
```

How to solve this? What's the best practice?

Answer (score 1):

`drake` targets should return fixed data objects that can be stored with `saveRDS()` (or alternative kinds of files if you are using [specialized formats](https://books.ropensci.org/drake/plans.html#special-data-formats-for-targets)). I recommend having a look at https://books.ropensci.org/drake/plans.html#how-to-choose-good-targets. There issues with defining a running instance of a Shiny app as a target.

1. As long as the app is running, `make()` will never finish.
2. It does not really make sense to save the return value of `shinyApp()` as a data object. That's not really what a target is for. The purpose of a target is to reproducibly cache the results of a long computation so you do not need to rerun it unless some upstream code or data change.

Instead, I think the purpose of the app target should be to deploy to a website like https://shinyapps.io. To make the app update when `df` changes, be sure to mention `df` as a symbol in a command so that `drake`'s static code analyzer can pick it up. Also, use `file_in()` to declare your Shiny app scripts as dependencies so `drake` automatically redeploys the app when the code changes.

```
library(drake)

plan <- drake_plan(
  df = faithful,
  deployment = custom_deployment_function(file_in("app.R"), df)
)

custom_deployment_function <- function(file, ...) {
  rsconnect::deployApp(
    appFiles = file,
    appName = "your_name",
    forceUpdate = TRUE
  )
}
```

Also, be sure to check the dependency graph so you know `drake` will run the correct targets in the correct order.

```
vis_drake_graph(plan)
```

[image]

In your previous plan, the command for the app did not mention the symbol `df`, so `drake` did not know it needed to run one before the other.

```
plan <- drake_plan(
  df = faithful,
  app = shinyApp(ui, server)
)
vis_drake_graph(plan)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for drake, I wasn't clear if this was fully resolved for the initial query and I also am not quite there. When I used custom_deployment_function with this faithful app (https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/basics.html), only changing faithful$waiting to df$waiting, but still get "closure not subsettable". The app works perfectly on its own outside of drake, but seems like some data and/or packages from the drake plan may not be getting passed into Shiny.

Comment: Maybe change df to a name that does not conflict with a base function? If that doesn’t work or does not generate a useful error message, I think this would be easier to troubleshoot in a new post with an end to end reproducible example.

Comment: I couldn't get there changing df so put up a new post.

Comment: Thanks. Would you comment with the link? Having trouble finding it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62903543/how-to-deploy-shiny-app-to-shinyapps-io-from-drake-plan