# How to deploy shiny app to shinyapps.io from drake plan

Tags: r, shiny, drake-r-package, rsconnect

This is a follow-on question from closing the loop on passing the app and data to a Shiny deployment function:

[How to use shiny app as a target in drake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61359114/how-to-use-shiny-app-as-a-target-in-drake/61366467#61366467)

I would like to deploy a Shiny app directly from a drake plan as below.

```
library(drake)
library(shiny)

plan <- drake_plan(
  cars_data = mtcars,
  deployment = custom_deployment_function(file_in("app.R"), cars_data)
)

custom_shiny_deployment <- function(file, data_input) {

    rsconnect::deployApp(
    appFiles = file,
    appName = "cars",
    forceUpdate = TRUE
  )
}

Saved as "app.R" in project working directory (the app works outside of drake if data_input <- mtcars) :

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    selectInput("variable", "Variable:",
                c("Cylinders" = "cyl",
                  "Transmission" = "am")),
    tableOutput("data")
  ),
  server = function(input, output) {
    output$data <- renderTable({
      data_input[, c("mpg", input$variable), drop = FALSE]
    }, rownames = TRUE)
  }
)
```

Logs from shinyapps.io shows "cars_data" from drake is not being passed to the Shiny server "data_input" in the custom_deployment_function environment:

```
2020-07-14T20:12:57.418989+00:00 shinyapps[2569696]: htmltools version: 0.5.0
2020-07-14T20:12:57.419186+00:00 shinyapps[2569696]: Using pandoc: /opt/connect/ext/pandoc2
2020-07-14T20:12:57.589960+00:00 shinyapps[2569696]: Using jsonlite for JSON processing
2020-07-14T20:12:57.593223+00:00 shinyapps[2569696]: 
2020-07-14T20:12:57.593224+00:00 shinyapps[2569696]: Starting R with process ID: '25'
2020-07-14T20:12:57.628389+00:00 shinyapps[2569696]: 
2020-07-14T20:12:57.628390+00:00 shinyapps[2569696]: Listening on http://127.0.0.1:38608
2020-07-14T20:13:14.686424+00:00 shinyapps[2569696]: Running on host: e89f96d02b6e
2020-07-14T20:13:14.691423+00:00 shinyapps[2569696]: Server version: 1.8.4-11
2020-07-14T20:13:14.691436+00:00 shinyapps[2569696]: LANG: en_US.UTF-8
2020-07-14T20:13:14.691436+00:00 shinyapps[2569696]: R version: 4.0.0
2020-07-14T20:13:14.691437+00:00 shinyapps[2569696]: shiny version: 1.5.0
2020-07-14T20:13:14.691467+00:00 shinyapps[2569696]: rmarkdown version: (none)
2020-07-14T20:13:14.691648+00:00 shinyapps[2569696]: Using pandoc: /opt/connect/ext/pandoc2
2020-07-14T20:13:14.691475+00:00 shinyapps[2569696]: knitr version: (none)
2020-07-14T20:13:14.857243+00:00 shinyapps[2569696]: Using jsonlite for JSON processing
2020-07-14T20:13:14.691443+00:00 shinyapps[2569696]: httpuv version: 1.5.4
2020-07-14T20:13:14.895595+00:00 shinyapps[2569696]: 
2020-07-14T20:13:14.691480+00:00 shinyapps[2569696]: jsonlite version: 1.7.0
2020-07-14T20:13:14.860404+00:00 shinyapps[2569696]: 
2020-07-14T20:13:14.860404+00:00 shinyapps[2569696]: Starting R with process ID: '41'
2020-07-14T20:13:14.895596+00:00 shinyapps[2569696]: Listening on http://127.0.0.1:42022
2020-07-14T20:13:14.691496+00:00 shinyapps[2569696]: RJSONIO version: (none)
2020-07-14T20:13:14.691506+00:00 shinyapps[2569696]: htmltools version: 0.5.0
2020-07-14T20:15:57.441648+00:00 shinyapps[2569696]: Running on host: a2e664ad9837
2020-07-14T20:15:57.447236+00:00 shinyapps[2569696]: Server version: 1.8.4-11
2020-07-14T20:15:57.447326+00:00 shinyapps[2569696]: R version: 4.0.0
2020-07-14T20:15:57.447337+00:00 shinyapps[2569696]: knitr version: (none)
2020-07-14T20:15:57.447337+00:00 shinyapps[2569696]: rmarkdown version: (none)
2020-07-14T20:15:57.447327+00:00 shinyapps[2569696]: shiny version: 1.5.0
2020-07-14T20:15:57.447260+00:00 shinyapps[2569696]: LANG: en_US.UTF-8
2020-07-14T20:15:57.447337+00:00 shinyapps[2569696]: httpuv version: 1.5.4
2020-07-14T20:15:57.447338+00:00 shinyapps[2569696]: jsonlite version: 1.7.0
2020-07-14T20:15:57.447338+00:00 shinyapps[2569696]: RJSONIO version: (none)
2020-07-14T20:15:57.667089+00:00 shinyapps[2569696]: 
2020-07-14T20:15:57.447494+00:00 shinyapps[2569696]: Using pandoc: /opt/connect/ext/pandoc2
2020-07-14T20:15:57.630039+00:00 shinyapps[2569696]: Starting R with process ID: '24'
2020-07-14T20:15:57.626886+00:00 shinyapps[2569696]: Using jsonlite for JSON processing
2020-07-14T20:15:57.447347+00:00 shinyapps[2569696]: htmltools version: 0.5.0
2020-07-14T20:15:57.630037+00:00 shinyapps[2569696]: 
2020-07-14T20:15:57.667090+00:00 shinyapps[2569696]: Listening on http://127.0.0.1:40107
2020-07-14T20:16:14.758082+00:00 shinyapps[2569696]: Warning: Error in renderTable: object 'data_input' not found
2020-07-14T20:16:14.772348+00:00 shinyapps[2569696]:   108: renderTable [/srv/connect/apps/cars/app.R#13]
2020-07-14T20:16:14.772349+00:00 shinyapps[2569696]:   107: func
2020-07-14T20:16:14.772350+00:00 shinyapps[2569696]:    94: origRenderFunc
2020-07-14T20:16:14.772350+00:00 shinyapps[2569696]:    93: output$data
2020-07-14T20:16:14.772350+00:00 shinyapps[2569696]:    13: runApp
2020-07-14T20:16:14.772351+00:00 shinyapps[2569696]:    12: fn
2020-07-14T20:16:14.772351+00:00 shinyapps[2569696]:     7: connect$retry
2020-07-14T20:16:14.772352+00:00 shinyapps[2569696]:     6: eval
2020-07-14T20:16:14.772352+00:00 shinyapps[2569696]:     5: eval
```

Apologies if this is trivial, but between drake and shiny, it is escaping me.

Comment: You may want to use this tag: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/drake-r-package; our tag for drake doesn't look like what you want ;) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/drake

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now that I see how you are deploying the app, I can say that this is expected behavior. Yes, your `custom_shiny_deployment()` has access to the data, but the deployed app does not because `rsconnect::deployApp()` does not ship objects from the calling environment. If you want the data to be available to the app, I recommend saving it (and tracking it with `file_in()` and `file_out()`) then passing it to the `appFiles` argument of `deployApp()` via `custom_shiny_deployment()`.

### EDIT

Your `app.R` can stay like it is.

`app.R` is the same as what you wrote.

```r
library(shiny)

cars_data <- readRDS("cars_data.RDS")

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    selectInput("variable", "Variable:",
                c("Cylinders" = "cyl",
                  "Transmission" = "am")),
    tableOutput("data")
  ),
  server = function(input, output) {
    output$data <- renderTable({
      cars_data[, c("mpg", input$variable), drop = FALSE]
    }, rownames = TRUE)
  } 
)
```

But from `drake`'s side, you need something like `file_in()` and `file_out()` to ensure the correct targets run in the correct order and in response to changes to `cars_data.RDS` and `app.R`.

```r
library(drake)

plan <- drake_plan(
  cars_data = mtcars,
  save_cars = saveRDS(cars_data, file_out("cars_data.RDS")),
  deployment = rsconnect::deployApp(
    appFiles = file_in("app.R", "cars_data.RDS"),
    appName = "cars",
    forceUpdate = TRUE
  )
)

make(plan)
```

If you really want `appFiles` to be `NULL`, `drake` still needs `file_in()` so it knows to depend on physical files.

```r
plan <- drake_plan(
  cars_data = mtcars,
  save_cars = saveRDS(cars_data, file_out("cars_data.RDS")),
  deployment = deploy_app(file_in("cars_data.RDS", "app.R"))
)

deploy_app <- function(...) {
  rsconnect::deployApp(
    appFiles = NULL,
    appName = "cars",
    forceUpdate = TRUE
  )
}
```

Either way, I recommend checking the plan with `plot()` or `vis_drake_graph()` before you run it with `make()`. Both plans above show `deployment` downstream of the data file (with incoming arrows) which is exactly what we want.

```r
plot(plan)
```

[image]

Without these file markers, there is a chance that `drake` will deploy the app before the data is ready to go.

```r
disconnected_plan <- drake_plan(
  cars_data = mtcars,
  saveRDS(cars_data, "cars_data.RDS"),
  deployment =  rsconnect::deployApp(
    appFiles = NULL,
    appName = "cars",
    forceUpdate = TRUE
  )
)

plot(disconnected_plan)
```

[image]

Comment: So, to be fuzzy, but don't pipe file_in to the custom_shiny_deployment() function in drake_plan? instead: (1) save cars_data to disc, say as RDS with file_out as a line in the drake_plan, (2) bring cars_data back from disc with file_in into the custom_shiny_deployment() env (3) hand over to the deployApp appFiles param from within the custom_shiny_development() env?

Comment: Yes, that should work. `rsconnect::deployApp()` only requires the name of the data file, so there should be no need to reread the data itself. Reading the data from storage will need to be the app's responsibility.

Comment: In summary, if I save to disc from drake_plan, and then re-load the libraries and data from disc within app.R as a completely separate environment, it all works. It works with the appFiles() parameter set to NULL, and without file_out() or a custom_shiny_deployment() helper. I was thinking of the data and the env flowing within the drake_plan. I'm not sure if this is what you were advising, but I couldn't figure out that way, so will have to leave that for someone more knowledgeable. Posting an answer.

Comment: Please see the new edit to my answer. I think it spells out the details.

Comment: That works a charm, thank you so much for adding it and the explanation helps a lot for understanding how it works